# haskell error parse error on input '|'

Tags: parsing, haskell, input, greatest-common-divisor

I'm trying to write a Greatest Common Divisor function in haskell. This is what I have so far:

```
gcd1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
gcd1 a b
    | a == 0 = b
    | b == 0 = a
    | otherwise = gcd (mod a b)
```

When I try to compile, I get that error. I've read about how haskell uses white space to determine where a functions declaration starts and where the body begins, but I keep trying with different amount of spaces and get the same error. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: wild guess - are you mixing tabs and spaces? - turn on `-Wall` -there should be a warning then about that or do a search and replace `s/\t/    /g` just to be sure

Comment: I put it in a file + a `where gcd = undefined` and it compiled w/o any problems

Answer (score 2):

On the last line, gcd needs to be applied on 2 arguments. You are only applying it to one -> (mod a b). Also, as others mentioned, you are probably mixing up your spaces and tabs. I recommend only using spaces.

One more thing, when defining the GCD function, it was probably intended for you NOT to use the predefined gcd function in your implementation.